# Como gerar dados para Graficos

Tags: jquery, array, gráfico

Estou fazendo uma pagina que terá vários tipos de gráficos... Mas minha base esta vindo por jQuery, Exemplo:

```js
var wo = new Array();
var listItemEnumerator = this.customlist.getEnumerator();

while ( listItemEnumerator.moveNext() ) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    wo.push({ ID: oListItem.get_id(), Country: oListItem.get_item( 'Country' ) });
}
```

E com esse objeto eu irei gerar os gráficos... mas se fosse SQL, seria fácil, por exemplo, fazer um `GROUP BY`... ate o momento estou fazendo as comparações por jQuery mesmo, mas queria saber se tem um jeito mais fácil, ou algum plugin que faça essa seleção na minha base.

Comment: Você não recebe um objeto ou algo do tipo? Poste ele...

Comment: sim e esta ali o codigo de como eu construo meu objeto

Comment: Você quer poder fazer um GROUP BY (por exemplo) em um array javascript de forma facil?

Comment: Você está usando alguma biblioteca de gráficos? Essa base que está vindo por jQuery vem de uma base de dados? Se sim, você poderia fazer o group by na base de dados antes de gerar o objeto Javascript.

Comment: sim, o `GROUP BY ` tambem.. como eu disse, irei gerar varios gráficos na página, então preciso de algo facil pra manusear minha base por javascript

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos eu não consigo fazer os comandos na base de dados =/ não tenho acesso

Comment: Tem o [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq), já utilizei essa biblioteca e ele me atendeu muito bem, não utilizei a parte dos `GROUP BY` (nem há na documentação mas se olhar no fonte há o método `group()`), sempre utilizei mas a parte de filtros e sort.

Comment: @Fernando valeu, vou tentar!

Comment: @Fernando vc q já usou essa biblioteca pode me ajudar então... olhei um exemplo na pagina e esta bem assim: `jlinq.from(data.users).select()`   
no meu caso, é só colocar o meu objeto(`wo`) no lugar de `data.users`?

Comment: @Thiago, edite a pergunte e post um exemplo de seu array com uns 10 itens e que tipo de operação você gostaria de fazer com ele, que vejo aqui como fazer (se possível) e posto como resposta se der certo. Mas respondendo sua pergunta, sim, o `data.users` do exemplo é a lista/array onde será aplicado os comandos/filtros/operações, no seu caso parece ser o `wo`.

Comment: @Fernando no post tem exatamente o código que uso pra construir meu array de objetos... mas pelo jeito estou fazendo algo de errado... o script está retornando a seguinte msg: _jLinq can only query arrays of objects._  
acredito q seja algum ajuste na construção do array..

Comment: @Fernando agora editei e coloquei o codigo completo... assim q chegarmos a uma solução, basta vc responder o post q marcarei como resposta

Comment: @Thiago, esse erro ocorre quando você tenta passar para o jLinq um objecto que não é um array. Se pesquisar no seu fonte pela mensagem de erro você vai ver essa verificação.

Comment: @Fernando mas olhando o meu código, parece estar tudo certo na construção do array objeto...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16042/discussion-between-thiago-and-fernando).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há a biblioteca [jLinq](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq), já utilizei essa biblioteca e ela me atendeu muito bem, não utilizei a parte dos `GROUP BY` (nem há na documentação mas se olhar no fonte há o método group()), sempre utilizei mas a parte de filtros e sort da biblioteca.

Mas verificando aqui a parte de `group by` também funciona corretamente, apesar de não estar nos demos do site do desenvolvedor, fiz alguns exemplos para lhe ilustrar o seu funcionamento:

```js
// filtro nomes de paises que iniciam "B" na lista
var result = jlinq.from(array)
.starts("country.nome", "B")
.select();
```

E um exemplo de `GROUP BY`:

```js
// Agrupa array por nome do pais
var resultGroup = jlinq.from(array)
.group("country.nome");
```

Segue [esse exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/4zL5m/3/) que ilustra melhor seu funcionamento.

**Edit**

Conforme comentário de @Thiago, surgiu a duvida de como especificar os campos (ou formato) do retorno em uma consulta com a biblioteca [jLinq](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq). Então criei um exemplo também para esse situação:

```js
// você consegue fazer um select no que você quer retornar
var result = jlinq.from(array)
.starts("country.nome", "B")
// o 'rec' é um alias da consulta
.select(function(rec) {
    // returnando um objeto no formato que você desejar
    return {
        id:rec.id,
    };
});
```

Ou ainda conforme a duvida de @Thiago, no caso dele pode-se até simplificar e retornar apenas um Array de ids:

```js
var result = jlinq.from(array)
   .starts("country.nome", "B")
   .select(function(rec) {
       return rec.id
});
```

Segue o [exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/wQsme/1/) dessa nova implementação.

Comment: surgiu uma duvida.... por ex: `var result = linq.from(wo).starts("country.nome", "B").select(); console.log(result);` esse codigo vai mostrar o objeto inteiro, contendo ID e Nome... tem como eu retornar apenas o que eu quero? no caso o ID

Comment: @Thiago, você pode especificar seu select como demostrado no exemplo no [site do desenvolvedor](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq/demo#) (Demo Refined Selecting), fiz também [esse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/wQsme/) para lhe ilustrar melhor o uso.

Comment: @Thiago, atualizei a resposta veja se lhe atende?

Comment: sim, voce me ajudou muito! =D